# (JDK 11) Run a JAR Archive through reflection which depends on Libraries

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin

**Note**: I have very little experience with the Module system introduced in Java 9.

I have a Java Process which should run another Jar file by loading and executing it through reflection.
Note that both Jar files depend on the JavaFX framework which got detached from the JDK in Version 11 and as a result could get loaded a second time.

Here the Original version which worked on JDK version 8:

```
val ideFile = File(binFolder, "Sk-IDE.jar")
val classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() as URLClassLoader
val method = URLClassLoader::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL::class.java)
method.isAccessible = true
method.invoke(classLoader, ideFile.toURI().toURL())
val coreManager = Class.forName("com.skide.CoreManager")
val instance = coreManager.newInstance()
coreManager.getDeclaredMethod("bootstrap", Array<String>::class.java).invoke(instance, State.args)
```

(The Reflective call to addURL was necessary because otherwise the loader Jar was unable to load its fxml files)

This approach throws this Exception on JDK 11:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

The approach to create a new `URLClassLoader`:

```
val child = URLClassLoader(arrayOf(URL(ideFile.toURI().toURL().toString())), Installer::class.java.classLoader)
val coreManager = Class.forName("com.skide.CoreManager", true, child)
val instance = coreManager.newInstance()
Platform.runLater {
    coreManager.getDeclaredMethod("bootstrap", Array<String>::class.java).invoke(instance, State.args)
}
```

Throws a JavaFX related Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" [20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR] java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at com.skide.installer.Installer$start$2$1$1.run(Installer.kt:249)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   ... 6 more
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR] Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:9

[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:930)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2450)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at com.skide.CoreManager$bootstrap$1.invoke(CoreManager.kt:47)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at com.skide.CoreManager$bootstrap$1.invoke(CoreManager.kt:24)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at com.skide.CoreManager.bootstrap(CoreManager.kt:136)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   ... 12 more
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.skide.gui.controllers.SplashGuiController
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:928)
[20.11.2018 20:13:41 | ERROR]   ... 21 more
```

Whats the best way to solve this?

Regards,
Liz3

**EDIT**

With the help of xtratic, the solution was actually straight forward:

I simply added the `child` URLClassloader to the CoreManager#bootstrap reflective call, the bootstrap method of the CoreManager(loaded jar) than passes that URLClassloader to all FXML loaders.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace of your `LoadException`?

Comment: no, here the full stacktrace: https://hastebin.com/lesorudewa.cs

Comment: Ohhhh... FXML is using the built in classloader to load the FX beans, which of course doesn't know about those classes.

Comment: You'll probably need to call `FXMLLoader.setClassLoader(urlClassLoader)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using the new `URLClassLoader` it seems like the method **is** being invoked but is throwing a `javafx.fxml.LoadException` which gets wrapped by the `PrivilegedActionException` and `InvocationTargetException`.

Even though you load your class with your own `URLClassloader` it looks like the FXML parser is trying to load the FX beans with the built-in classloader, which doesn't know about those classes in the FXML.

**You'll need to make FXMLLoader use the right classloader that contains all the classes referenced by the fxml**. Read the source of `FXMLLoader` to get an idea of how it handles classloading. You may need to modify the library doing the fxml loading if possible. Look into `FXMLLoader.setClassLoader(urlClassLoader)` or possibly setting a `SecurityManager` so that the `FXMLLoader` will use the calling classloader.

---

`FXMLLoader.java`

```
/**
 * Returns the classloader used by this serializer.
 * @since JavaFX 2.1
 */
@CallerSensitive
public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
    if (classLoader == null) {
        final SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        final Class caller = (sm != null) ?
                Reflection.getCallerClass() :
                null;
        return getDefaultClassLoader(caller);
    }
    return classLoader;
}

private static ClassLoader getDefaultClassLoader(Class caller) {
    if (defaultClassLoader == null) {
        final SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (sm != null) {
            final ClassLoader callerClassLoader = (caller != null) ?
                    caller.getClassLoader() :
                    null;
            if (needsClassLoaderPermissionCheck(callerClassLoader, FXMLLoader.class.getClassLoader())) {
                sm.checkPermission(GET_CLASSLOADER_PERMISSION);
            }
        }
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    }
    return defaultClassLoader;
}
```

---

I had a guess that Java11 may have changed it's classloader.

See [this link](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/#Casting-To-URL-Class-Loader) (contents pasted below)

> **Casting To URL Class Loader**
> Java 9 and the module system improved the platform’s class loading strategy, which is implemented in a new type and in Java 11 the application class loader is of that type. That means it is not a `URLClassLoader`, anymore, so the occasional `(URLClassLoader) getClass().getClassLoader()` or `(URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` sequences **will no longer execute**. This is another typical example where Java 11 is backwards compatible in the strict sense (because that it’s a URLCassLoader was never specified) but which can nonetheless cause migration challenges.
>
> **Symptoms**
> This one is very obvious. You’ll get a ClassCastException complaining that the new AppClassLoader is no URLClassLoader:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader
    at monitor.Main.logClassPathContent(Main.java:46)
    at monitor.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

> **Fixes**
> The class loader was probably cast to access methods specific to URLClassLoader. If so, you might have to face some serious changes.
> ...
> If you’ve used the `URLClassLoader` to dynamically load user provided code (for example as part of a plugin infrastructure) by appending to the class path, then you have to find a new way to do that as it can not be done with Java 11. **You should instead consider creating a new class loader for that**. This has the added advantage that you’ll be able to get rid of the new classes as they are not loaded into the application class loader. You should also read up on layers – they give you a clean abstraction for loading an entirely new module graph.

Comment: > "So, correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like the method is being invoked but is throwing a javafx.fxml.LoadException which gets wrapped by the other two exceptions. My guess is that the new URLClassLoader you create is missing some FXML files that it's trying to load. What is the full stack trace of your LoadException?" - Correct

Comment: Did you find which resources it was trying to load, and make sure they are included in your Classloader?

Comment: No, since i don´t exactly know how to load them, i am assuming: `val child = URLClassLoader(
                    arrayOf(URL(ideFile.toURI().toURL().toString())), Installer::class.java.classLoader)` is loading all classes and resources.

Comment: > "You should instead consider creating a new class loader for that." Seams like the best solution

Comment: I think you've already covered that part with creating the `URLClassLoader`, I think now you just need to set that classloader on your `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: Yeah right, but that needs to happen in the new process right? So adding a function to the loaded jar which sets the ClassLoader and invoking that function through reflection

Comment: Yea, I think the `CoreManager` class that was loading the fxml needs to set the classloader on the `FXMLLoader`. Read the source of `FXMLLoader` to get an idea of how it handles class loading. You might also be able to set a `SecurityManager` to help get past this issue.